# React action, ESLint: Argument 'dispatch' should be typed with a non-any type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a `React` action like this:

```
export const sigIn = () =>
  async (dispatch: any) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_REQUEST
    });
  };
```

I'm getting a:

```
ESLint: Argument 'dispatch' should be typed with a non-any type.(@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types)
```

as a warning on the `async`. Why?

Edit: for both answers, I put the `Dispatch` type from `redux` but I still have the warning:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error because you used `any`, and your lint rules forbid that. The fix is to use the correct type for dispatch, which can be imported from redux:

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';

export const sigIn = () => 
  async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_REQUEST
    })
  };
```

Comment: The fix for missing a return type on the function is to add a return type to the function. Looks like it should be `Promise<void>`.

Comment: Yes, `Promive<void>` works, thanks. I will pick this answer as the correct one, becase was the first

Answer (score 1):

You can either disable the rule in your *eslint* config or add a sufficient type.

```
import { Dispatch } from 'react-redux';

async (dispatch: Dispatch<{ type: SIGN_IN_REQUEST }>): void => {
   dispatch({
     type: SIGN_IN_REQUEST
});
```

Comment: @pmiranda Then add a `void` at the end, because it doesnt return anything.